# Can't resolve error in .Rmd file <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval ->

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to write a document that discusses using errors to communicate problems with the arguments to the user.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the .Rmd file to knit.  A short example:

````
Intro text

```{r}
some_function <- function(x, y)
{
  if (x < 0) stop("x must be greater than 0")
  x + y
}

some_function(3, 2)
```

```{r}
some_function(-3, 2)
```
````

When I try to knit this to any format, I get the error

```
Quitting from lines 14-15 (test.Rmd) 
Error in some_function(-3, 2) : x < 0
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> some_function

Execution halted
```

Everything I've read so far points to this being a problem with either a) not loading a package, or b) an incorrectly set path in the Rmd file.

Since I'm only using base functions here and am not referencing any files (that I'm aware of, anyway), I don't think either of those are my problem (but I'll be happy to be wrong).

Any tips on what I need to do to get the document to knit?

**Solution**

Add the following to the top of the .Rmd

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(error = TRUE)
```
````

Short explanation, RMarkdown v1 used `error = TRUE` by default, but RMarkdown v2 uses `error = FALSE`.  See the link in Josh's comment below.

Comment: Yes, it will stop knitting on an error (clearly occurs at the some_function(-3, 2) call. What is your desired result? It prints the error or something?

Comment: That's correct.  I want it to display the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't compile with the button in rstudio. Try:

```
library("knitr")
knit2html("file")
```

Comment: That's interesting.  This renders the file as I want it.  The next question is whether I can apply this so that I can write this up as a vignette in a package.

Comment: see here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_migrating_from_v1.html . It's just a different default chunk setting to knitr.

Comment: Well now I feel silly.  I thought I had tried that already.  Which can only mean I've been awake too long.  Thanks, Josh.

Comment: If you're reading this on 2017, then `rmarkdown::render('file.rmd', output_format = 'html_document')`

Comment: if you're reading this in 2019 then the comment above for 2017 still works

Comment: If you're arriving here because of `withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval`, be sure to also make sure you are using `\`\`\`{r}` and not `\`\`\`r`

Comment: If you're reading this in 2020, you will get an error asking you to call rmarkdown::render() probably because your R Markdown is v2

Comment: For me the problem was because I was loading packages in a chunk that was being cached. For some reason these packages are not visible to later chunks. Either disable the cache or move the loading to a different chunk.

Comment: hi @ChechyLevas what do u mean by that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case (June 2021, R 4.06, latest RStudio), replacing

````
```{r eval=T, message=F, warning=F, error=F}
````

with

````
```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, error=FALSE}
````

fixed this problem:

> Error in options$error && options$include : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y' Calls:  ... call_block -> block_exec -> in_dir -> evaluate -> `

Very odd....