# Trouble kniting document

Tags: r, knitr

I get this announcment when I try to knit my doc:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> eval -> .handleSimpleError -> h -> cat -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'H2_Miles_McAnulty.knit.md': Operation not permitted
Execution halted.
```

I have my chunk set up as:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
options(Encoding ="UTF = 8")
```

So, I tried what is on this post: [Can't resolve error in .Rmd file <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval ->](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519673/cant-resolve-error-in-rmd-file-anonymous-withcallinghandlers-withvisi)

What is wrong?

Comment: You may want to check the file permissions. How to go about this depends on the operating system you're using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. As Roman alluded to in the comments, it was due to the lack of file permissions. Adding R to the list of allowed applications through controlled folder access on Windows Security solved the problem.